# i want to find the => and <= of two table in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, select

```
Importer| Fruits |ValueFrom |ValueTo
Mark      Banana     $1        $10
Mark      Banana     $11       $20
John      Banana     $1        $10
John      Banana     $11       $20
Mark      Mango      $1        $10
Mark      Peach      $11       $20
John      Apple      $1        $10
John      Mango      $11       $20
```

I want to fillet my dataset to select one row by selecting a Importer and Fruits and a value between ValueFrom and ValueTo

SELECT       Importer,Fruits, ValueFrom, ValueTo, 
FROM            tblDatabase
WHERE        (Importer=@Importer),(Fruits=@Fruits), ' this is as far as i got

Comment: This sounds easy to solve, can you provide more info, such as a sample data set & expected values?

Comment: i am pretty new to this not even 4 days yet but i am a fast leaner
importer = Mark name and in valuefrom = 1 and ValueTo = 10
importer = Mark name and in valuefrom = 20 and ValueTo = 30
i want input 28 in value and it select the second importer

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset and expected values to demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am pretty new to this not even 4 days yet but i am a fast leaner
importer = Mark name and in valuefrom = 1 and ValueTo = 10
importer = Mark name and in valuefrom = 20 and ValueTo = 30
i want input 28 in value and it select the second importer

Comment: I provided a solution for SQL server database since the DB was not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the SQL "BETWEEN" operator which specifies the lower and upper bounds of a range. It includes both lower & upper values.

```sql
-- select results (this finds all fruits for Mark where 18 is in the value range)
SELECT *
FROM tblDatabase 
WHERE
    Importer='Mark'
    AND
    18 BETWEEN ValueFrom AND ValueTo;
```

Comment: how can i provide a sample of my dataset?

Comment: You can edit your original question and paste a tab or comma-separated list of data to the end of the question. The sample needs to be a few lines only. Please be careful not to expose any identifiable customer info such as names or emails.

Comment: i try to put a sample of the dataset try to made it look like a table

Comment: Answer updated using your actual data. Be aware that your WHERE statement is wrong - it is a syntax error. You need to join multiple clauses with the AND operator as in my example.

Comment: i dont think i am typing the question well only if i could tell you direct

Comment: Can you type the expected result, using your dataset?

Comment: i already have a dataset so i dont ned to create one and when i try the declare it say not valid
i want to filter the dataset to find a record from the importer and fruits and a value between ValueFrom and ValueTo

Comment: My example contained an explanation of how this works. I removed the explanation & updated the SQL for your database only.

Comment: ok thank you it selecting the row but how can i run it from two filter box one for value and one for importer it also give me this error The Declare SQL construct or statement is not supported. but run the query just the same

Comment: Changed to a fixed query.

Comment: thank you again david for you continued patience as i am a total nube i am working with vb ever thing so far as you put it work with a slight problem

Answer (score 0):

my table was not set to int it was sent to varchar(50) now i can run my query with out a problem with the code below thanks again

SELECT        Importer,Fruits, ValueFrom, ValueTo
FROM            tblDatabase
WHERE        (ImporterType = @Importer) AND (@ValueChosen BETWEEN ValueFrom AND ValueTo)